# Should input values outside of contract be unit tested?

Tags: c, unit-testing

I'm refactoring a huge C library with legacy code, where many functions have pointers on arguments list. I also write unit tests for newly created functions to make sure, that I haven't broken anything (aside from all good things which come from unit tests, that's my primary motivation). I'm also not allowed to change library's API, only the code below it.

Usually the result of my work looks like this (it's proprietary code, so I can't post actual examples):

externalApi.h:

```
/**
 * Documentation1
 */
bool someExportedFunction1(uint8_t* buffer, size_t len);

/**
 * Documentation2
 */
bool someExportedFunction2();
```

refactoredCode.h:

```
/**
 * Documentation of internal function1
 */
bool internalFuntion1(uint8_t* buffer, size_t len);


/**
 * Documentation of internal function2
 */
bool internalFuntion2(uint8_t* buffer, size_t len);
```

externalApi.c:

```
bool someExportedFunction1(uint8_t* buffer, size_t len)
{
    if (NULL == buffer)
    {
        ERROR("Meaningful error log");
        return false;
    }

    if (!internalFunction1(buffer, len))
    {
        ERROR("Other error log");
        return false;
    }

    if (!internalFunction2(buffer, len))
    {
        ERROR("Yet another error log");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool someExportedFunction2()
{
    uint8_t lBuffer[10] = {};

    if (!internalFunction1(lBuffer, sizeof(lBuffer))
    {
        ERROR("Interesting error log");
        return false;
    }

    uint8_t* ptr = malloc(10);
    if (NULL == ptr)
    {
        ERROR("Malloc error");
        return false;
    }

    if (!internalFunction2(ptr, 10)
    {
        free(ptr);
        ERROR("Boring error log");
        return false;
    }

    free(ptr);

    return true;
}
```

refactoredCode.c

```
bool internalFuntion1(uint8_t* buffer, size_t len)
{
    if (NULL == buffer)
    {
        ERROR("Guess what, a meaningful error log");
        return false;
    }

    // Do stuff
    return true;
}

bool internalFuntion2(uint8_t* buffer, size_t len)
{
    if (NULL == buffer)
    {
        ERROR("Last meaningful error log");
        return false;
    }

    // Do stuff
    return true;
}
```

Those are just simple examples to illustrate the point, there are countless other versions of the same problem.

Now, all unit tests I write include checking what happens if I pass NULL as argument, no matter how low level function I'm testing (even if I'm 100% sure there is no way NULL will ever be passed as an argument).

One of my coworkers however, disagrees with me saying, that NULL is outside functions contract, and proper approach would be to write assertions instead of `if`s. Such assertions should not be unit tested (even with `EXPECT_DEATH` macro), because unit tests are also documentation of proper usage of functions, and using NULL is not allowed.

We can sum up arguments from both sides like this:

Pro "write `if` and unit test it" approach:

1. With ERROR logs we can easily find not only which function detected NULL, but also where was it called (pseudo-stacktrace), making debugging significantly easier
2. If we don't test checking for NULLs how can we be sure that we covered all the cases (with assertions or `if`s, doesn't matter)?
3. People generally either don't read documentation until it's too late, or sometimes they code on Friday afternoon - we can't expect them to be perfect programmers all the time
4. We can't predict what changes will be made to the code in the future, so it's better to have tests warned us about every change, so we can decide whether it was intentional or not
5. If assertion is detected in a test (and we didn't expect it, it's totally due to an error in the code) the whole testing application is killed and other, unrelated, tests are not performed until we fix the problem.

Pro "assert and don't test" approach:

1. Maintaining such test may cost us a lot of time, because we have no standard way of handling programming problems like passing NULL
2. Passing NULL pointer should outside function's contract - handling NULL is changing the contract, so we must always check for it, which means a lot of work in the future with adding those ifs
3. Assertions don't go into release code - which is good, because when we make a release the code should be tested sufficiently to make sure, that no mistake slipped through
4. Passing NULL is usually undefined behaviour - upper layers of application usually can't handle such error properly anyway, so it's safer to simply kill the process
5. Unit tests should be an example of how the function should be used and passing NULL is exactly the opposite of it

In the end none of us could convinced the other and the debate finished without a conclusion and we fell back on *Argumentum ab auctoritate* because the other guy is simply way more experienced than I am.

But I'm still not convinced, so I'm asking the question here:

Taking under consideration all arguments for both approaches I presented, and all those I'm not aware of:

**Should arguments outside function's contract be checked with `if` and unit tested, or asserted and not tested?**

Answer (score 2):

1. If a certain section of your code is performance sensitive, avoiding these checks in those sections makes sense.
2. On all other parts of the code, it makes sense to have all the checks and create log files to help with tracking. Defensive programming like that will save your back lots of times.

Comment: And check to see how much effect there is on performance, before eschewing defensive programming safety checks